Расположение символьной информации при сборке ядра Linux
Само задание звучит так - собрать ядро без использования символьной информации под вашу
целевую платформу.
То, что символьная информация - это информация для дебаггинга я понял (см. Символьная информация при сборке ядра Linux).
Отключает/включает ее строчка CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO в конфиге. Вопрос заключается в том, куда сохраняется эта информация после компиляции? То есть в какой директории, в каком файлике можно посмотреть ее и факт ее наличия/отсутствия?

вы, наверно, не поверите, но отладочная информация при компиляции программы помещается (либо не помещается, если вы принудительно эту возможность отключаете) внутрь этой самой компилируемой программы.

Возможно Вам необходимо почитать этот документ https://docs.kernel.org/kbuild/modules.html в частности о Module.symvers file
